# HOW GET ELEMENT which has the maximum childs in XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath, count, max, element

I created one table with number of columns. Now i want to get column name which have maximum number of element. How do get that result
**in xpath query?**

**Example Code:**

```
<table>
            <colum>

                <namecolum>aaa</namecolum>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </colum>
            <colum>

                <namecolum>bbbb</namecolum>
                <td>33</td>  
                <td>423</td>
            </colum>
            <colum>
                <namecolum>cccc</namecolum>
                <td>323</td>
                <td>212</td>
                <td>00</td>
                <td>667</td>
             </colum>
 </table>
```

Any other code is appreciable if any one can provide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone cant ans..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select `colum` such that there is no `colum` with more amount of `td` tags

```
//colum[not(count(td) < //colum/count(td))]/namecolum/text()
```

Comment: it's depend on version of Xpath. That will work on Xpath 1.0

Comment: `not(count(td) < //colum/count(td))` is equal to `max(td)`

Comment: ahh... Thanks you!!